# Copy the Shell script output in a File

Tags: bash, terminal, copy, output

I have combine alias of two script. Following alias **works fine** in my OS setup

```
alias build_command 'directory_1/foo.sh build'
alias copy_command 'directory_2/bar.sh'
alias build_copy 'build_command && copy_command'
alias bc build_copy
```

The problem is when I want to dump the terminal output in a file. Can any one please tell me how I can do this ? FYI, I tried `bc > temp.txt` in terminal, but does not work and I am not allow to modify the build and copy script:(

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: First, you shouldn't use aliases but functions. Now, if you really want to use your `bc` alias and redirect output, use: `{ bc; } > temp.txt`, otherwise only the output of `copy_command` is redirected.

Answer (score 0):

From `man bash`:

> For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions.

---

The problem when you enter `bc > temp.txt` is that bash expands the aliases as:

```
directory_1/foo.sh build && directory_2/bar.sh > temp.txt
```

so that only the output of `directory_2/bar.sh` is redirected.

To fix this, use:

```
{ bc; } > temp.txt
```

so that, thanks to the grouping, the output of the full command is redirected.

---

Another option is to use a function:

```
bc() { build_copy; }
```

and now `bc > temp.txt` do what you expect.

---

On a side note: `bc` is a rather poor name choice as there's already a utility called `bc`…